# Swiping on ListView Items - WP8.1

Tags: c#, listview, windows-phone-8, win-universal-app, swipe-gesture

The new ListView for WP8.1 has IsSwipeEnabled option. But I dont see any events which capture the gesture. How do I capture a left or right swipe on a listview item? The samples for Universal Apps do not contain Gestures. The ListView sample does not contain gestures either.

Some pointers or examples or MSDN links please.

P.S I am creating a Universal app

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [GestureRecognizer class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br241937) .  The swipe gesture is

```C#
 Windows.UI.Input.GestureSettings.CrossSlide
```

Microsoft's Demo on how to use Gestures: [Input: Gestures and manipulations with GestureRecognizer](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Manipulations-and-gestures-362b6b59)

Good luck.